# Stack layered lookup

Tags: vba

This is code I wrote to check a product structure from 1 table in a database. It's based on a type which can have area(s) and area(s) can have group(s).

I have:

```
type and code area: blank group: blank
type and area and code group:blank
type and area and group and code
```

As you can see, it is stacked and the lookup is layered to find the correct code. Is there something I can do to improve it?

```
Public Function StackLayeredLookup()
    Dim Start As Integer
    Dim lStart As Integer
    Dim cRows As Integer
    Dim lRows As Integer

    Dim TypeValue As String
    Dim TypeCode As String
    Dim AreaValue As String
    Dim AreaCode As String
    Dim GroupValue As String
    Dim GroupCode As String

    Dim aValue As String
    Dim dValue As String

    Const TypeCol = "G"
    Const AreaCol = "H"
    Const GroupCol = "I"

    Const RegCol = "E"

    Const tValueCol = "P"
    Const aValueCol = "Q"
    Const gValueCol = "R"

    'Region = "MEX"

    Start = 2

    cRows = Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    lRows = Worksheets("TagCodes").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Do Until Start = cRows


        TypeValue = Worksheets(2).Range(TypeCol & CStr(Start)).Value
        AreaValue = Worksheets(2).Range(AreaCol & CStr(Start)).Value
        GroupValue = Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Value

        If (TypeValue <> "") Then

            TypeCode = ""

            lStart = 1

            Do Until TypeCode <> "" Or lStart = lRows + 1

                If (Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("A" & CStr(lStart)).Value = TypeValue) Then

                    aValue = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("C" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                    gValue = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("D" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                    If (aValue = " " And gValue = " ") Then

                        Worksheets(2).Range(tValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("B" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                        TypeCode = Worksheets(2).Range(tValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value

                        Exit Do

                    End If

                Else

                    lStart = lStart + 1

                End If

            Loop
            If (TypeCode = "") Then

                Worksheets(2).Range(TypeCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            Else

                Worksheets(2).Range(TypeCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

            End If
            If (TypeCode <> "" And AreaValue <> "") Then

                AreaCode = ""

                lStart = 1

                Do Until AreaCode <> "" Or lStart = lRows + 1

                    If (Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("A" & CStr(lStart)).Value = AreaValue) Then

                        gValue = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("D" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                        If (Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("B" & CStr(lStart)).Value = TypeCode And gValue = " ") Then

                            Worksheets(2).Range(aValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("C" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                            AreaCode = Worksheets(2).Range(aValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value

                            Exit Do
                        Else

                            lStart = lStart + 1

                        End If

                    Else

                        lStart = lStart + 1

                    End If

                Loop
                If (AreaCode = "") Then

                    Worksheets(2).Range(AreaCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Else

                    Worksheets(2).Range(AreaCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

                End If
                If (TypeCode <> "" And AreaCode <> "" And GroupValue <> "") Then

                    GroupCode = ""

                    lStart = 1

                    Do Until GroupCode <> "" Or lStart = lRows + 1

                        If (Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("A" & CStr(lStart)).Value = GroupValue) Then

                           If (Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("B" & CStr(lStart)).Value = TypeCode And Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("C" & CStr(lStart)).Value = AreaCode And Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("D" & CStr(lStart)).Value <> " ") Then

                                Worksheets(2).Range(gValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value = Worksheets("TagCodes").Range("D" & CStr(lStart)).Value

                                GroupCode = Worksheets(2).Range(gValueCol & CStr(Start)).Value


                                Exit Do
                           Else

                            lStart = lStart + 1

                           End If

                        Else

                            lStart = lStart + 1

                        End If

                    Loop
                    If (GroupCode = "") Then

                        Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Else

                        Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

                    End If
                Else

                    Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                End If
            Else

                Worksheets(2).Range(AreaCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

            End If
        Else

                Worksheets(2).Range(TypeCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                Worksheets(2).Range(AreaCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                Worksheets(2).Range(GroupCol & CStr(Start)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

        End If

    Start = Start + 1

    Loop
End Function
```